# Splashscreen works imperfectly with Support Action Bar in Android

Tags: android, splash-screen

I have a support action bar app in Android with a drawer layout and also a splash screen for the app.

The issue is when I launch my app, the ActionBar flashes for a second before the splash screen.

How do I fix this?

Here is my code for the splash screen:

```
public class SplashScreen extends ActionBarActivity {

    // Splash screen timer
    private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 3000;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash_activity);

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            /*
             * Showing splash screen with a timer. This will be useful when you
             * want to show case your app logo / company
             */

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // This method will be executed once the timer is over
                // Start your app main activity
                Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, ZMainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

                // close this activity
                finish();
            }
        }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
    }

}
```

Here is my manifest:

```
    <activity
        android:name="info.androidhive.androidsplashscreentimer.SplashScreen"
        android:label="MeriMasjid.com"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
```

Please note that I cannot use any theme for my activity since it is an app compat app.

***SOLUTION :***

converting ActionBarActivity to Activity for Splashscreen and Applying @android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar to its entry in Manifest worked

Comment: You need AppCompat when you want actionbat below 11. If you don't want then don't use appcompat. Also actionbar is available natively from api level 11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just because you use AppCompat does **not** mean every activity needs to extends `ActionBarActivity` - only those that need an action bar should extend `ActionBarActivity`. For your splash screen, you can extend `Activity` (if you don't need any fragments) or `FragmentActivity` (if you do need fragments). In either case, you can then use styles such as `@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar` without exceptions.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that it takes time to go to `oncreate` method to make your activity full screen thus the `actionbar` flashes for a moment before it disappear.

Instead doing progmatically apply it in your manifest instead inside your activity tag

**sample:**

```
 <activity
    android:name="info.androidhive.androidsplashscreentimer.SplashScreen"
    android:label="MeriMasjid.com"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
    >
```

**for appcompat:**

you need to open your `style.xml` in your `values folder` and replace everything by this:

```
<resources>

<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light"></style>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

after add this in your manifest:

```
 <activity
    android:name="info.androidhive.androidsplashscreentimer.SplashScreen"
    android:label="MeriMasjid.com"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    >
```

Comment: 06-24 09:10:42.991: E/AndroidRuntime(7814): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-24 09:10:42.991: E/AndroidRuntime(7814): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.qiblaclean/info.androidhive.androidsplashscreentimer.SplashScreen}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.

Comment: unofortunately this didn't work . Got the same error

Comment: Fixed the issue !! see Update